# Вывод символа новой строки в неизвестный поток

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

Как правильно вывести символ новой строки в поток `std::ostream`, передаваемый функции?

```
out << '\n'; // (1)

out << std::endl; // (2)

out << out.widen('\n'); // (3)
```

Comment: Зависит от того, что вам нужно. Просто символ - '\n', со сбросом буфера - `endl`.

Comment: @Harry а `widen()` зачем?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/widen